# Is there a source for real-world Spring and Hibernate examples?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have looked through a number of Spring and Hibernate tips and have not found a real-world example in 'tutorial' form. By real-world I mean (for example):

1. A search is used to retrieve a Person object. That object detail is then displayed. A field of the object is then modified by the user and the form is submitted and the object is saved. Most examples perform retrieval and save in the same method, which is identical to the example on the Spring website.
2. An object has more than 3 or 4 fields, including fields that normally would not be on the form (e.g. createdDate, createdBy, lastModifiedDate, lastModifiedBy).
3. A command object is associated with the form. So we have person.jsp, PersonForm.java, and PersonController.java.

Pointers to the three examples mentioned above would be appreciated.

Comment: Better to show your attempts, and where you're having problems. Other wise this question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 5):

One good example application using the technologies you are interested in (and that is not a toy application) is [petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/).

A real world site that is powered by the latest Java and Spring tech is [spring.io](http://spring.io/)! Check out the github repository [here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan). A series of blog posts on the development of that site can be found [here](http://spring.io/blog/2014/04/18/project-sagan-upgrading-to-jdk-8)